# Is it possible to use rainbow logo here?

Tags: discussion, design

> ***Disclaimer :*** *This question is asking just for curiosity. Nothing more nothing less*

***[Please see this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1)*** StackOverflow took a huge step forward to change their logo. Is it possible to use a rainbow logo for at-least one day in our community site ?

I know, US court rule (which I believe one of the huge step man-kind taken) has nothing to do with Magento. But when we think, being neutral is the best thing in our community. Irrespective of our colour, religion, place, men, women or gay or whatever, we are here only because of the immense love towards Magento. Since it is all about neutrality, the court rule is a huge proclaim of such neutrality (which I personally believe).

Is it possible to make a rainbow logo for our logo. At-least for that big "***M***"

or

Is it even possible to use an customized logo in special occasions ?

---

Note : I am not from US and not a gay too :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the logo.
"We" are not in charge of how the website looks. I don't know what happens after/if the website graduates. Maybe we will be able to change it then.

But if you want my personal opinion, I would rather not change it.
I always prefer to stay away from political, religious, philosophical and any other sensitive debates.
This is not what SE is about.
On the other hand, feel free to change your avatar to what ever you want (as long as it's decent). And if narrow minded people are offended by it, then be it.

Comment: Thanks for your official + personal opinion. But there is one fact still exist. Stackoverflow is a platform to ask programming questions. Political, religious, philosophical debates has nothing to do with it. Still they changed their logo to show the support. Google did it.. twitter did it. Then why dont we.. :-) 

But as you said, we are now in beta and we are unable to change the logo. That is sad. But making "rainbow profile pics" is an outstanding thought. I prefer that in this case. Thanks again Marius

Answer (score 4):

This discussion about being neutral is a long and old one. If you ask me, you can't be neutral. We need freedom for everyone. As long as their is a rule or law where a notably group is not allowed to do something but all others are, this law has to fall.

Germany is still fighting for every piece of equal rights, because our <strike>stupid</strike> conservative politician are "defending the family".

I'm totally in. If we can manage it, I'm for changing it. Not a few days, just change it.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your support. But as a community, by changing the logo what we mean is, "Yes, we, as Magento Community Members supports anything which stands for EQUALITY".  and additionally I am indian. where religion, family interest, social influence come first rather than love when it comes to MARRIAGE. This is an illness of our society. It should change. So I wish "rainbow" stands for ever. But to show the support, I would like to change our logo for two days. that is enough I think

Comment: If nice people are feeling more included with such a logo, I would love to just stay with it, but two days are better than nothing. On the other hand, if people dislike it because what it stands for, I'm fine if they stay away :p

Comment: "Stay Away" - cool... I loved that statement. lol :P